# Hotkey/shortcut for starting and stopping JetBrains macros

Tags: macros, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I'm using JetBrains PHPStorm but I believe this question relates to the other JetBrains IDEs.

I'm wondering how I can create/assign a hotkey/shortcut for starting/stopping macro recording.  I'd also like to be able to play my temporary macros with a hotkey as well.

For example: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> (start recording macro), type some stuff.... <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (stop recording macro),  then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (play back macro).

Comment: How is it related to AutoHotkey?  Do you want a solution created outside of the IDE?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, good point.  I think autohotkey will be a better option... I just need to figure out how to have autohotkey running all the time so I don't have to manually have to turn it on every time i need to do a macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` | `Keymap`, **Add Keyboard Shortcut**:

[image: keyboard shortcut]

Comment: Seems to work.  I think I'm going to end up just using autohotkey so I can do this no matter what editor i'm using.

Comment: I suggest `control+\` for mac peaps. It works for me!